# How to write if there is no file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The user types the name of file. If he writes the wrong name of the file and python has an error like "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '5'". How can I write to user that he has typed the wrong name of the file?
This code doesn't want to work:

```
try: 
    filename = input ("Your file name")
except OSError as e:
    print('We have an error: ', str(e))
```

Comment: `input` never throws a `FileNotFoundError`. `open` does.

Comment: Which part of the code shown do you imagine is checking if the file exists?

Comment: I don't know. I really need only to write to user something if he types the unexisting name of file.